# Open socket connection to python socket JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tcp, bridge, web-serial-api

I am working on TINET, a way to connect a TI-84 Plus CE graphing calculator.
Everything works fine for connection but after a poll, I saw that users preferred not to download a python script to bridge between serial and TCP server.

So we've decided to make a page on our website to bridge that way, but after a quick search, we didn't found any way to open a connection to a python socket using the `socket` library :(

I've tried many things, I've searched for hours here on stackoverflow and other sites and gave for once AI a try but didn't find any solution

The bridge is something that bridges from SRL to TCP and vice-versa (without blocking like [this python script](https://github.com/tkbstudios/tinet-bridge/blob/dev/tinet-bridge.py) .

Any help would be so appreciated ☺️

Comment: In short: Javascript im Browser does not provide a generic socket API. You have WebSockets which covers some use cases, but this is its own protocol on top of TCP and does not help if you need full control over the application protocol on top of TCP directly. Does this answer your question? [Connecting to TCP Socket from browser using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407778/connecting-to-tcp-socket-from-browser-using-javascript), [Create TCP/IP socket in client-side javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125356/create-tcp-ip-socket-in-client-side-javascript)